# How to find the rate of effusion given rates?

Tags: homework, gas-laws

**Question**

At $25~^\circ\mathrm{C}$, a sample of $\ce{NH}$ effuses at the rate of $0.050$ moles per minute. Under the same conditions, what is the molar mass of a gas that effuses at approximately one half of that rate?

**My steps and thoughts**

I converted $25~^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ to $298~\mathrm{K}$ and then I was thinking of using $pV=nRT$ and I got stuck.

I am thinking of using molar mass, but I don't know how to incorporate that.

Please, only give **hints** not the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

This question seems to be a simple application of Graham's Law (assuming you know Graham's Law), i.e the rate of effusion of a gas is inversely proportional to the square root of the mass of their particles. This empirical law can be formulated as follows:

$$\frac{\text{Rate}_1}{\text{Rate}_2} = \sqrt{\frac{\text{M}_2}{\text{M}_1}}$$

Solution:

> I don't know what the OP meant by $\ce{NH}$, I assume the gas in question is $\ce{NH3}$ with rate of effusion ($R_1$) = 0.050 $\mathrm{mol \min^{-1}}$.
>
>  $R_2 = \frac{R_1}{2}$ and $M_1 = 17.031$, plugging all of this in
>
>  $M_2 = M_1\cdot \left (\frac{R_1}{R_2} \right )^2 = 4\cdot M_1 = 68.124$